# creating git repository for use in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, git

I'm trying to create a git repository that I can use to source control some code that I am developing on a Linux VM (Windows host).  In the host, I have created an empty git repository at location

`C:\Users\foo\bar\.git`

that I want to clone to my virtual machine.  Now, from my virtual machine, I can ssh into my windows host using the address of the virtual box host-only network.  Essentially ssh'ing upstream of where the VM gets its internet from.  However, I cannot clone the repository, consistently getting

`exec request failed on channel 0` errors

How do I go about fixing this?  I've followed several of the git tutorials online (including [this one from Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository#git-init)) and ([this one I've found elsewhere on StackExchange](http://toroid.org/git-website-howto)) with no luck.

Comment: What's the URL for the git repo?

Comment: The URL is username@192.168.7.3:/foo/bar/.git.  The IP address is the address that VirtualBox uses for sending internet to the VM I think.  But I know I can ssh to my host machine through that same IP.

Comment: I'm sightly confused on your actual setup, but I'm almost positive you're doing it wrong. Before I explain the right steps, are you wanting to use BitBucket or GitHub to host your code remotely? Both are basically the same but there are a very very minor differences between each site. Such as private repos. Also, which Linux distro are you using on the VM?

Comment: I'm not planning on hosting the code remotely, at least not yet, as it isn't ready for public consumption.  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on my VM

Comment: Sorry for such a long delay. I don't think something has to be complete to be on GitHub or BitBucket. I have all kinds of things that are incomplete that are out there. It's just a space to store your code, to where it can be accessed easily from all over. If you want to hide your code from the public, BitBucket allows you to create a private repo as a free user. Otherwise you're going to have to setup a git daemon with Cygwin. Let me know which option you prefer.

Comment: I don't plan on using either BitBucket or GitHub.  This code is to stay on my own network.